# Rotate discrete dataset Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a discrete dataset, `X=[x1,x2,..,x12] & Y=[y1,y2,...,y12]`. X ranges from [-25, 0] and Y ranges from [1e-6, 1e0]. X does not increase uniformly - as x approaches a value of 0, data sampling density increases from increments of 2.5 to increments of 1. Each x value is units of cm. I cannot get a good fit to the data from fitting a function (I've tried quite a few). I'm left with the discrete data. My need is to sweep the X, Y data completly around the Z axis and put the resulting swept data values into a matrix Z of size (51, 51). I've tried using the cylinder function, `[u,v,w] = cylinder(Y)` thinking I could extract the data or create a matrix Z from [u, v, w]. I can't seem to sort that out. `surf(u,v,w)` plots *almost* correctly - the scaling on the (u, v) axes ranges from [-1, 1] instead of [-25, 25]. This is, I assume, because I'm using `cylinder(Y)`. When I try `[u,v,w] = cylinder(X,Y)` I get, `error: linspace: N must be a scalar`. It seems like there should be a better way then my approach of using cylinder to take the X & Y data, interpolate between points (to fill Z where data isn't), rotate it, and put the result into a matrix Z. Any suggestions are welcome. I'm using Octave 6.3.0. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to compute matrix `R=sqrt(x,y)`, presumably with `x` and `y` running from -25 to 25, then interpolate for each `R` value in your `(X,Y)` data, to obtain your desired `Z`? I assume `X==R` and `Z==Y`?

Comment: Hi Cris, thanks for your reply. Yes, it sounds like that would work. You're correct `X==R & Z==Y`. Based on your suggestion, here's what I tried. `x=[-25:1:25]; y=[-25:1:25]'; R=sqrt(x.^2.+y.^2);` I then tried to use `interp and interp2` from the examples in documentation, but don't seem to be able to connect the dots (no pun intended :) to get `Z` from `Y` and `R`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a matrix R containing distance from origin values.
Use for loops and single value interpolation to cover the R space.
Place the interpolated values into the matrix Z.

```
% Original data X = [-25,-22.5,...,0]; size(X) = 1 12
% Original data Y = [1e-6, 1.3e-6,...,1] size(Y) = 1 12

u = [-range(X):1:range(X)]; v = [-range(X):1:range(X)]';
R = -sqrt(u.^2.+v.^2);
Z = zeros( 2 .* range(X) + 1);
for i = 1:size(R,1)
  for j = 1:size(R,2)
    if R(i,j) < min(X); Z(i,j) = 0; endif
    if R(i,j) >= min(X); Z(i,j) = interp1(X,Y,R(i,j)); endif
  endfor
endfor
```